# How Exclude some files from Eclipse Java EE Web Application project Deployment Assembly

Tags: eclipse, war

As described into question title, I've an Eclipse Java EE Web Application project. Into WebContent folder I've some files and subfolder in which there are .DS_store OsX system files that cause some problem because they are always included when I export into war file.

I know that there is a way for excluding a file or folder but only into src folder, not into WebContent!

Any ideas?

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not remove the from (delete or just move to another folder) if they shouldnt be in your webcontent folder?

Otherwise you could use the **Deployment Assembly** settings. Open it from your project properties, and remove the top WebContent and add what you really want to get packaged.

[image]

Also you can exclude the files/folder by setting a resource filter. Add a filter... as shown below:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Fine solution.

Comment: Any way to exclude the files from the build with resource filter but still see them in the tree?

Comment: Yes, resource filters work, but will hide the files in the project explorer - not that great

Comment: @Kawu you can always use the navigator if you want to see the file structure and content. But if you want to exclude then there is a reason why you exclude, and why do you still want to exclude and in the same time see em in the explorer? :\ Let me know your case so I get a clear picture - you must have a good reason I think

Comment: Someone on the project put a project itself under that tree, much as a sub project (it's the application's theme), so the code must be reachable from Eclipse but not the final deployment.

Comment: hard to tell anything without more details or see the entire setup, but in my ears that doesnt sound any good way. You can do the relationship in other way and keep the projects separated as a project should. It will be easier and more modular. You have a project properties and build path, and projects where you should have the dependencies given. I m not sure what the team try to achieve by nestling the projects like this.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [war task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/war.html) of ant. say you located your ant build file directly inside your web-project then the following work for you which excludes folder *.DS_store* and all its contents from exported war file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project basedir="." default="war" name="TestWeb">
    <target description="export-war" name="war">
        <war destfile="/home/guest/Desktop/TestWeb1.war" webxml="WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml">
            <fileset dir="WebContent">
                <exclude name="**/.DS_store/**"/>
            </fileset>
            <classes dir="build" />
        </war>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks, seems to be a valid solution. ;)